# Java: >>> operator vs 0xff

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, signed, bit

The task is to fetch each byte from a given integer. This is the approach I saw somewhere:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
bytes[0] = (byte) ((id >> 24) & 0xff);
bytes[1] = (byte) ((id >> 16) & 0xff);
bytes[2] = (byte) ((id >> 8) & 0xff);
bytes[3] = (byte) (id & 0xff);
```

It would result in the same break-up as this:

```
bytes[0] = (byte) (id >>> 24);
bytes[1] = (byte) (id >>> 16);
bytes[2] = (byte) (id >>> 8);
bytes[3] = (byte) (id);
```

where, `id` is an integer value and will `ALWAYS` be unsigned. In fact, I don't see the need to `AND with 0xff` in the first approach (isn't it? since we're always using the least significant byte).

Is there any difference in the two approaches and which one is preferred?

Comment: "id is an integer value and will ALWAYS be unsigned" An `int` is always signed in Java. Do you mean that it's positive? That does not matter, though. Both approaches are equivalent - even with `>>` instead of `>>>`

Comment: I meant, I know the value which id will be holding and it'll never hold a negative integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `& 0xff` in the upper example either, because your example always chops off the bits that are different in sign-extended vs. non-sign-extended numbers.

Here is why: when you shift a number right by `n` bits using `>>`, the upper `n` bits will get the same value as the most significant bit of the number being shifted. The behavior of `>>>` differs only in that `>>>` forces the upper `n` bits to zero. The lower `(32-n)` bits are the same regardless of the kind of the shift that you use.

None of your examples shifts by more 24 bits, so the lower eight bits would be the same if you replace `>>>` with `>>` in your bottom example.

Since it is entirely unnecessary to mask with `0xff`, I would use your second snippet using `>>` or `>>>` for the operator, because the code is shorter.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. Thanks a lot for confirming..It was a very basic and an extremely important doubt.